# How to create a blob container with Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

Using Logic Apps I am trying to copy blobs from one container into several separate dynamically created containers however there doesn't appear to be a "create container" action in Logic Apps.

I have tried using the "Create Blob" action with the desired container name specified as part of the "Blob Name" parameter however this fails with a 404 message.

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Specified container telemetery-30dfb0bd-73b0-42a3-8677-63bde2fd4b43 does not exist.\r\nclientRequestId: blahblahh-e60e-44e1-aec4-c32a21659257",
  "error": {
    "message": "Specified container telemetery-30dfb0bd-73b0-42a3-8677-63bde2fd4b43 does not exist."
  },
  "source": "blahblha-ne.azconn-ne-01.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

The original request is -

```
{
    "method": "post",
    "queries": {
        "folderPath": "/",
        "name": "/telemetery-30dfb0bd-73b0-42a3-8677-63bde2fd4b43/timeline,xml",
        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": "True"
    },
    "path": "/datasets/default/files",
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/blahblah-6866-4c8c-b3f1-41039ad2b3eb/resourceGroups/RG-blahblahg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob"
        }
    },
    "body": "file content"
}
```

IS there a way to create a blob container us Logic Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, there's no "create container" operation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/

What you can do is write an Azure Function and chain it as part of your workflow in order to create the container:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#create-a-container

Comment: Put in a feature request!

Comment: not sure why they didn't implement it yet... I am sure there must be a good reason for it

Comment: I've up voted an existing feature request at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33202429-add-option-to-create-container-in-an-azue-blob-sto M Chandler suggests that this can already be done, and his response is why I raised the question here, however I do wonder if he is confusing folders with containers.

Comment: he is...there's no support for creating containers at this moment

Comment: I used the Azure functions as recommended here, however it is a shame as I was hoping on moving the management of the process outside of development.  However I found a few of these unsupported scenarios so I've rewritten the entire Logic App as functions.

Answer (score 2):

For now there is no action to create blob container, you could implement it with azure function like Thiago proposed. Suppose you could use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-container) to do it. The below test use the sas token to do it you could try other authorize way.

[image]

Comment: that's interesting, did you use the "Get SAS Uri by path" connector to get the SAS uri for a container that doesn't yet exist?